# How and which one better approach for Java BigDecimal initialization?

Tags: java

I have to assign 0 to **creditBalacne** now here we can get two way

```
private BigDecimal creditBalance = new BigDecimal(0);
```

and other way

```
private BigDecimal creditBalance1 = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

which one is better and why? and What way a developer to prefer ?

Comment: The second one is preferred generally. It'll give you the instance stored in a cache of BigDecimal values; thus avoiding the creation of a new object.

Comment: Would modifying `creditBalance1` after using the second method throw an error since `ZERO` is a final object? @ZouZou

Comment: @boxed__l No, `creditBalance1` is not `final` and `BigDecimal` instances are immutable so you would have to reassign the result of your op. to the variable anyway.

Comment: @ZouZou  is Cache not vaiable for BigDecimal will this approach  through Exception

Comment: @subodh Why would there is no cache? It's hardcoded in the `BigDecimal` class. It'll always be there (unless maybe you use reflection but that's another story...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option will create new objects (and later garbage)

If performance matters, the second option may be preferable.  If in doubt, use the approach which is clearest and simplest to you.

BTW Another option is to use

```
private BugDecimal creditBalance1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
```

This will use a cache of values where possible (and create new objects if not)

Comment: private BigDecimal creditBalance1 = BigDecimal.ZERO; will through exception in any case like if cache not available it will throw exception? As u define another approach?

Comment: @subodh Can you clarify what you mean?  What is the exception thrown?  Why wouldn't the cache be available?

Comment: As u mentioned another way what is the problem to use like this private BigDecimal creditBalance1 = BigDecimal.ZERO;

Comment: @subodh You need to know all the constants which are available, and this is less than the number of values cached. i.e. it is fine for `ZERO` but not a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the big scheme of things it doesn't matter which one you use.
But since there already is a constant for zero, you might as well use it.